# Convert JSON file to AVRO

Tags: python, json, avro

I am new to AVRO and Python. I have a use case where I want to convert the JSON file into an Avro file. I have stored my schema in .avsc format and the JSON data in .json format. Now I want to put the JSON file and .avsc file together and serialize the JSON file into Avro. Below is my code, I am getting an error that "avro.io.AvroTypeException: The datum file.json is not an example of the schema". I am not sure what I am doing wrong. In my writer.append statement I want the script to take data from JSON file and append it in .avro file but in a serialized format. I am not sure how to handle this, any help will be highly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
import avro.schema
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter
from avro import schema, datafile, io
import json
from avro import schema, datafile, io


def json_to_avro():
        fo = open("laird.txt", "r")
        data = fo.readlines()
        final_header = []
        final_rec = []
        for header in data[0:1]:
            header = header.strip("\n")
            header = header.split(",")
            final_header = header
        for rec in data[1:]:
            rec = rec.strip("\n")
            rec = rec.split(" ")
            rec = ' '.join(rec).split()
            final_rec = rec
        final_dict = dict(zip(final_header,final_rec))
        # print(final_dict)
        json_dumps = json.dumps(final_dict, ensure_ascii=False)
        # print(json_dumps)
        schema = avro.schema.parse(open("laird.avsc", "rb").read())
        # print(schema)

        writer = DataFileWriter(open("laird.avro", "wb"), DatumWriter(), schema)

        with open("laird.json") as fp:
            contents = json.load(fp)
            print(contents)

        writer.append(contents)

        writer.close()

json_to_avro()
```

Data in laird.avsc file:

```
{
  "name": "MyClass",
  "type": "record",
  "namespace": "com.acme.avro",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "event_type",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "event_data",
      "type": {
        "name": "event_data",
        "type": "record",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "device_id",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "user_id",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "payload",
            "type": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "name": "payload_record",
                "type": "record",
                "fields": [
                  {
                    "name": "name",
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "sensor_id",
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "type",
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "unit",
                    "type": "string"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "value",
                    "type": "float"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "channel",
                    "type": "int"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "timestamp",
                    "type": "long"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "client_id",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "hardware_id",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "timestamp",
            "type": "long"
          },
          {
            "name": "application_id",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "device_type_id",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "company",
      "type": {
        "name": "company",
        "type": "record",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "type": "int"
          },
          {
            "name": "address",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "city",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "country",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "created_at",
            "type": "int",
            "logicalType": "date"
          },
          {
            "name": "industry",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "latitude",
            "type": "float"
          },
          {
            "name": "longitude",
            "type": "float"
          },
          {
            "name": "name",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "state",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "status",
            "type": "int"
          },
          {
            "name": "timezone",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "updated_at",
            "type": "int",
            "logicalType": "date"
          },
          {
            "name": "user_id",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "zip",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "location",
      "type": {
        "name": "location",
        "type": "record",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "type": "int"
          },
          {
            "name": "address",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "city",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "country",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "created_at",
            "type": "int",
            "logicalType": "date"
          },
          {
            "name": "industry",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "latitude",
            "type": "float"
          },
          {
            "name": "longitude",
            "type": "float"
          },
          {
            "name": "name",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "state",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "status",
            "type": "int"
          },
          {
            "name": "timezone",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "updated_at",
            "type": "int",
            "logicalType": "date"
          },
          {
            "name": "user_id",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "zip",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "company_id",
            "type": "int"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "device_type",
      "type": {
        "name": "device_type",
        "type": "record",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "application_id",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "category",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "codec",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "data_type",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "description",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "manufacturer",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "model",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "name",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "parent_constraint",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "proxy_handler",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "subcategory",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "transport_protocol",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "version",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "created_at",
            "type": "int",
            "logicalType": "date"
          },
          {
            "name": "updated_at",
            "type": "int",
            "logicalType": "date"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "device",
      "type": {
        "name": "device",
        "type": "record",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "type": "int"
          },
          {
            "name": "thing_name",
            "type": "string"
          },
          {
            "name": "created_at",
            "type": "int",
            "logicalType": "date"
          },
          {
            "name": "updated_at",
            "type": "int",
            "logicalType": "date"
          },
          {
            "name": "status",
            "type": "int"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Data in laird.json

```
{
  "event_type": "uplink",
  "event_data": {
    "device_id": "fec5d310-88bf-11ea-aadf-2bd85a1038fa",
    "user_id": "ba5e224b-fcc2-4e1b-b2b3-97ef57b9ba60",
    "payload": [
      {
        "name": "Temperature",
        "sensor_id": "fef87bd0-88bf-11ea-ae96-6fae9a4d5562",
        "type": "temp",
        "unit": "c",
        "value": 21.9,
        "channel": 3,
        "timestamp": 1603300033446
      },
      {
        "name": "Humidity",
        "sensor_id": "fef399d0-88bf-11ea-a424-59b141c8d9bf",
        "type": "rel_hum",
        "unit": "p",
        "value": 74,
        "channel": 4,
        "timestamp": 1603300033446
      },
      {
        "name": "Battery",
        "sensor_id": "feef2d00-88bf-11ea-aadf-2bd85a1038fa",
        "type": "batt",
        "unit": "p",
        "value": 100,
        "channel": 5,
        "timestamp": 1603300033446
      },
      {
        "name": "RSSI",
        "sensor_id": "fef658f0-88bf-11ea-ae96-6fae9a4d5562",
        "type": "rssi",
        "unit": "dbm",
        "value": -42,
        "channel": 100,
        "timestamp": 1603300033446
      },
      {
        "name": "SNR",
        "sensor_id": "",
        "type": "snr",
        "unit": "db",
        "value": 10.2,
        "channel": 101,
        "timestamp": 1603300033446
      }
    ],
    "client_id": "1c46a2e0-88b9-11ea-90ae-77c0364d6e36",
    "hardware_id": "0025ca0a00008612",
    "timestamp": 1603300033446,
    "application_id": "shipcomwireless",
    "device_type_id": "16a4d0c0-3edf-11e9-bf5e-a180edbfa9bb"
  },
  "company": {
    "id": 6854,
    "address": "10500 University Center Dr",
    "city": "Tampa",
    "country": "United States",
    "created_at": "2020-04-27T19:44:46Z",
    "industry": "[\"Health Care\"]",
    "latitude": 28.045853,
    "longitude": -82.421,
    "name": "Dermpath Diagnostics Bay Area",
    "state": "FL",
    "status": 0,
    "timezone": "America/New_York",
    "updated_at": "2020-04-27T19:44:46Z",
    "user_id": "ba5e224b-fcc2-4e1b-b2b3-97ef57b9ba60",
    "zip": "33612"
  },
  "location": {
    "id": 8138,
    "address": "10500 University Center Dr",
    "city": "Tampa",
    "country": "United States",
    "created_at": "2020-04-27T19:44:46Z",
    "industry": "[\"Health Care\"]",
    "latitude": 28.045853,
    "longitude": -82.421,
    "name": "Dermpath Diagnostics Bay Area",
    "state": "FL",
    "status": 0,
    "timezone": "America/New_York",
    "updated_at": "2020-10-19T18:22:19Z",
    "user_id": "ba5e224b-fcc2-4e1b-b2b3-97ef57b9ba60",
    "zip": "33612",
    "company_id": 6854
  },
  "device_type": {
    "id": "16a4d0c0-3edf-11e9-bf5e-a180edbfa9bb",
    "application_id": "",
    "category": "module",
    "codec": "lorawan.laird.rs1xx",
    "data_type": "",
    "description": "Temp Sensor",
    "manufacturer": "Laird",
    "model": "RS1xx",
    "name": "Laird Temp & Humidity RS1xx Sensor - IoT in a Box",
    "parent_constraint": "NOT_ALLOWED",
    "proxy_handler": "PrometheusClient",
    "subcategory": "lora",
    "transport_protocol": "lorawan",
    "version": "",
    "created_at": "2019-03-05T00:39:09Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-03-05T00:39:09Z"
  },
  "device": {
    "id": 217200,
    "thing_name": "Slide/Block Warehouse STE250",
    "created_at": "2020-04-27T19:47:58Z",
    "updated_at": "2020-04-28T12:58:08Z",
    "status": 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

There are two problems. The first is in the schema. Anywhere that you currently have the following:

```
      {
        "name": "created_at",
        "type": "int",
        "logicalType": "date"
      },
```

Should instead be this:

```
      {
        "name": "created_at",
        "type": {"type": "int", "logicalType": "date"}
      },
```

After fixing that, the other problem is in your data. When you read in the JSON file, the `created_at` and `updated_at` fields are strings, but they need to be `datetime.date` objects. You can do this for each of them with something like the following:

```
from datetime import date
contents["company"]["created_at"] = date.fromisoformat(contents["company"]["created_at"].split("T")[0])
```

---

ORIGINAL:

The `writer.append` function does not take in the name of a JSON file. Instead it takes in the JSON object. So instead of:

```py
writer.append("laird.json")
```

You will want something like this:

```py
with open("laird.json") as fp:
    contents = json.load(fp)

writer.append(contents)
```

Comment: thanks for the response so I tried the code snippet you suggested in my code like below, but I am getting an error
     
        schema = avro.schema.parse(open("laird.avsc", "rb").read())
        print(schema)

        writer = DataFileWriter(open("laird.avro", "wb"), DatumWriter(), schema)

        with open("laird.json") as fp:
            contents = json.load(fp)

        writer.append(contents)

        writer.close()
json_to_avro()

Comment: Error: 

  File "C:\main.py", line 39, in <module>
    json_to_avro()
  File "C:\main.py", line 35, in json_to_avro
    writer.append(contents)
  File "C:Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\avro\datafile.py", line 227, in append
    self.datum_writer.write(datum, self.buffer_encoder)
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\avro\io.py", line 979, in write
    raise AvroTypeException(self.writers_schema, datum)
avro.io.AvroTypeException: The datum {'event_type': 'uplink', 'event_data': {'device_id':

Comment: You should update your question with the actual contents of laird.avsc and laird.json so that the example can be run. The exception you are now seeing looks like it is saying that your data isn't the same as the schema but the traceback is cut off so it's not possible to know what the problem is.

Comment: I have updated the question with the code and the files. Could you please help me debug this issue? I really have no clue what I am doing wrong. Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks a lot, Scott. Will try what you have suggested.

Comment: The solution worked. Thanks a lot, Scott for all your help!!

Answer (score 1):

you can try with fastavro and rec_avro module, here's some example

```
from fastavro import writer, reader, schema
from rec_avro import to_rec_avro_destructive, from_rec_avro_destructive, rec_avro_schema

def json_objects():
    return [{'a': 'a'}, {'b':'b'}]

# For efficiency, to_rec_avro_destructive() destroys rec, and reuses it's
# data structures to construct avro_objects 
avroObjects = (to_rec_avro_destructive(rec) for rec in json_objects())

# store records in avro
with open('json_in_avro.avro', 'wb') as x:
    writer(x, schema.parse_schema(rec_avro_schema()), avroObjects)

#load records from avro
with open('json_in_avro.avro', 'rb') as f_in:
    # For efficiency, from_rec_avro_destructive(rec) destroys rec, and 
    # reuses it's data structures to construct it's output
    loadedJson = [from_rec_avro_destructive(rec) for rec in reader(f_in)]

assert loadedJson == json_objects()
```

Comment: Thanks @batman. I will try it out. So if I understand correctly I should use the above function after I get the schema out of the json file. Sorry if I sound silly, but I have limited knowledge of Python and Avro.